# Cypress: Stub response for same route with three different responses

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, cypress

I have a single endpoint in the application. We hit the same api for each request with different action in the params.

URL:

```
/application/api
```

Sample Request Payload 1:

```
{
  "action": "CARD_TRANSACTION_HISTORY",
  "data": {
    "date_from": "2018-12-01",
    "date_to": "2018-12-31",
    "total": 5
  },
  "meta": {}
}
```

Sample Request Payload 2:

```
{
  "action": "CARD_BALANCE",
  "data": {
    "date_from": "2018-12-01",
    "date_to": "2018-12-31",
    "total": 5
  },
  "meta": {}
}
```

Sample Request Payload 3:

```
{
  "action": "CURRENCY_RATES",
  "data": {
    "date_from": "2018-12-01",
    "date_to": "2018-12-31",
    "total": 5
  },
  "meta": {}
}
```

the action in above request changes for different requests.

When the dashboard page is loaded, we trigger 3 **concurrent** AJAX POST requests with different actions.

Problem with cypress is you can only specify one response for a route, and other way to handle this is make sequential requests (which we can't do)

Even if we write response as a function it gets called only once.

Any ideas on how we can mock data on the basis of payload?

Comment: sorry, not understanding does each request have a query string or something that make them unique.. Is the action going in the the body?

Comment: Just edited the question with more sample payloads. Yes the action in payload is different and unique for each request

Comment: I was going to suggest writing the response as a function that returns one of the 3 payloads in order, until I read your last line.  I think you might be SOL.

Comment: Try this one : https://softans.com/question/cypress-stub-response-for-same-route-with-three-different-responses/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did one dirty work around that worked, I didn't like it but I am out of options.

I simply combined all the responses in the same response.

My Mock Response

```
{
  balance: {..},
  transactionHistory: {..},
  currencyRates: {..}
}
```

The each response handler simply processes part it is interested in, if one of the response is array, we'll need to change it to an object.

I'll be on a lookout for a better work around.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem and found @Richard Matsen's answer very useful, however when using the `whitelist` option it isn't possible to access `proxy.request`, which returns `undefined`. But if you use `onRequest` instead of `whitelist`, you can access the request and thus implement any action depending on that request's body.

So this should work:

```
cy.server({
  onRequest: (xhr) => {
    xhr.url = xhr.url + 
      xhr.request.body.action  == 'CARD_TRANSACTION_HISTORY' ? '?transactionHistory'
      : xhr.request.body.action  == 'CARD_BALANCE' ? '?balance'
      : xhr.request.body.action  == 'CURRENCY_RATES' ? '?currencyRates'
      : ''
  }
})
```

Comment: You must be doing something wrong when accessing proxy in the whitelist callback, as it works in my test.

Comment: This is better than using whitelist, which was intended for filtering and feels a bit hacky. I tried altering response in `onRequest` and `onResponse` (to no avail) but didn't think to apply the URL parameter there.

Comment: So after setting this param in the request url, then what? I'm still not able to use `cy.route({ url: '...?balance' }).as('balance')` because Cypress will not find a match?

Comment: @AicoKleinOvink were you able to get this working. I have all the steps in place but cypress can't match since the request don't have the query string attached!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another hack. It relies on your api ignoring url parameters and that the cy.server whitelist function is called before the request is made.

```
cy.server({
  whitelist: (proxy) => {
    proxy.url = proxy.url + 
      proxy.request.body.action  == 'CARD_TRANSACTION_HISTORY' ? '?transactionHistory'
      : proxy.request.body.action  == 'CARD_BALANCE' ? '?balance'
      : proxy.request.body.action  == 'CURRENCY_RATES' ? '?currencyRates'
      : ''
  }
})

const apiMocks = {
  balance: {..},
  transactionHistory: {..},
  currencyRates: {..}
}
cy.route('/application/api?balance', apiMocks.balance).as('balance')
cy.route('/application/api?transactionHistory', apiMocks.transactionHistory)
  .as('transactionHistory')
cy.route('/application/api?currencyRates', apiMocks.currencyRates).as('currencyRates')

cy.visit(...)

cy.wait('@balance').then(xhr => //should see correct mock here )
```

Answer (score 1):

if anyone comes to this question I probably found another hack, that worked for me (I'm using unfetch polyfill to work around fetch requests and cypress) - here is the code for one route.

```js
cy.route({
  url: '/api/ngfw/devices/search',
  method: 'POST',

  // Default response, when parametrs doesn't match
  response: [],

  onResponse: (xhr) => {
    xhr.response = { body: [] };
    const { body } = xhr.request;

    if (body.groupBy) {
      const [groupBy] = body.groupBy;
      if (groupBy === 'overallColor') {
        Object.defineProperty(xhr.xhr, 'responseText', {

          // Putting response inside
          value: JSON.stringify(mockData.totalsResult),

          enumerable: true
        });
      }
    }
  },
});
```