# In Cypress, how do I stub a POST API request with parameters in the body?

Tags: cypress, stub

I am writing an end-to-end test with Cypress and I would like to stub the network requests which my application makes. Specifically, I would like to stub out multiple POST requests which have parameters in the body and to change my simulated response based on those parameters.

I would like to do something like

```
cy.route({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/todos/add"
  params: {
    "urgency": 3,
    "stakeholder_id": "SKH001"
  },
  response: "fixture:add1.json",
})

cy.route({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/todos/add"
  params: {
    "urgency": 1,
  },
  response: "fixture:add2.json",
})
```

But after reading through 
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html and https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Arguments, I do not see a supported way of checking the arguments in the request being stubbed.

Can I accomplish this by passing a function to the `onRequest` parameter of `cy.route`? If so, what would I return from that function which tells cypress "this route actually does not handle this request"?

Comment: So you want to return a different fixture based on the body? See the *"Response Functions"* example in https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#With-Stubbing - is what you need in the `routeData`?

Comment: I believe response functions fire once only, not per route.

Comment: This question [Cypress: Stub response for same route with three different responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654626/cypress-stub-response-for-same-route-with-three-different-responses) may provide some ideas.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, do the parameters matter so you can return a different response?

Comment: @Maccurt yes, will update question to make that more clear.

Comment: Try this one: https://softans.com/question/in-cypress-how-do-i-stub-a-post-api-request-with-parameters-in-the-body/#comment-481

Answer (score 1):

If your Cypress version is greater than 6, you should refactor to use `intercept`. Intercept handles params really cleanly and you can assign parts of output to a file using the alias or in the callback.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.route({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/todos/add"
  body: {
    "urgency": 1,
  },
  response: "fixture:add2.json",
})
```

Comment: It's really useful in these cases to call out what changed, and provide an explanation for why it's important. In this case, I see that you changed `params` to `body`. But that is really easy to miss without an explanation. Can you update your answer?

Comment: This is also inaccurate. `body`, according to the official docs, is not available for `route`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [Mirage.js](https://miragejs.com/)

https://miragejs.com/docs/comparison-with-other-tools/#cypress-route-mocks

See their tutorial: https://miragejs.com/quickstarts/cypress/

Answer (score 0):

You can use intercept method too.

```
cy.intercept('POST', <your api end point>, {response:
<your json file path>}).as('postAPI')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you using intercept.  https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Arguments

```js
const handler = (req) => {
  if (req.body.urgency === 3) {
    req.reply({
      statusCode: 200,
      fixture: `your fixture`,
    }) 
  };
  if (req.body.urgency === 1) {
    req.reply({
      statusCode: 200,
      fixture: `your other fixture`,
    }) 
  };
}
cy.intercept('POST', yourURLMatcher, handler)
```