# How to access request body in cy.route response callback?

Tags: cypress

I have built something that can capture network requests and save them to a file. Currently I am now trying to build the second part which should return these captured requests, but running into some difficulties. Sometimes I have multiple requests going to a single method/url combination, and I need to return a different response depending on the request body. The problem I am facing is illustrated in the example below:

```js
cy.route({
    url: 'api.example.com/**',
    method: myMethod,
    response: routeData => {
        // I can set the response here
        // But I don't have access to the request body
    },
    onRequest: xhr => {
        // I can access the request body here
        // But I am not supposed/able to set the response
    },
})
```

If I understand the API docs correctly, I am supposed to set the response in the `response` callback. However, in that callback I do not seem to have access to the XHR object from which I could read the request body.

Is there a way to access the request body in the `response` callback?
Or, alternatively, is there a way to set the response from the `onRequest` callback?

---

**Update:** just saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62201936/1143502) which mentions a `body` property which can be added to the `cy.route` options object. I don't see this in [the cypress route docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html) so I don't know if this is even a valid option, and I also wouldn't know if making multiple calls to `cy.route` with an identical `method` and `url`, but a different `body` would produce the correct results. If this was of any use, I would have hoped to have seen some branching logic based on a `body` property [somewhere in this file](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/master/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/xhr.js#L352-L532), so I am not super hopeful.

Comment: I have come across: [Allow dynamic stubbing and responses](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/521) which is still an open issue with `cypress`! I have myself tried 'few of the proposed work arounds' but nothing worked :(

Comment: Yeah I tried most of the proposed solutions too with similar results :-(

Comment: Did you read this [blog](https://dev.to/digitaledawn/how-to-use-stub-multiple-api-requests-dynamically-in-cypress-40g7) as well? It mentions a 'workaround' with `xhook`.

Comment: @Sree.Bh I have read that too, and have tried implementing it like that. I got to the point where I was returning fixture data from the `xhook.before` callback. I tried several ways of returning that data, i.e. just returning it as in the blog link you posted, and also using the second `callback` parameter as in this example: https://github.com/jpillora/xhook/blob/gh-pages/example/fake-response.html. Both approaches didn't work for me. Also this way we don't see the requests on the network tab anymore....

Answer (score 0):

Cypress v6 comes with the `cy.intercept` API. Using that is much more convenient than using `cy.server` and `cy.route`.