# same api, but different response in cypress

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress, cypress-intercept

Can cypress version 6 handle same api, but diff responses?
If yes, is the following correct?
If we cannot, will cypress version 9 support this?

```
// * same api for each test, but diff response
const api = '/v1/test';

it('test 1', () => {
    cy.intercept(api, {res: '1'});
    // do stuff
});

it('test 2', () => {
    cy.intercept(api, {res: '2'});
    // do stuff
});

it('test 3', () => {
    cy.intercept(api, {res: '2'});
    // do stuff
});
```

There are some [hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654626/cypress-stub-response-for-same-route-with-three-different-responses), but looking for a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the "routes" by adding this code

```js
afterEach(() => {
  const routes = cy.state('routes')
  const keys = Object.keys(routes)
  console.log('Number of routes', keys.length)  // 1, 1, 1 - only one route exists per test
  const route = routes[keys[0]]
  console.log(route.handler.body)             // {res: '1'}, {res: '2'}, {res: '2'}
})
```

Note, the referenced question is about `cy.route()` which has less capability than `cy.intercept()`

Answer (score 0):

[From the `cy.intercept()` page,](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept)

> All intercepts are automatically cleared before every test.

So, if you are setting your intercepts on a per-test basis (in the `it()` blocks), then this should work as you'd expect, with each test having a different response for the same endpoint. As far as I know, this been the behavior of `cy.intercept()` since it was introduced, and should work with Cypress 6.